# How to add a math expression in the label outside of a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, labels

Adding a math expression as a label inside a node works fine:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[circle, draw] (c1) [label=left: text] {};
    \node[block, draw, right = of c1] (e1) {$1*1=1$};  
    \draw[->] (c1) -- (e1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

However, if I want to put the math expression next to the node (like I did with the 'text' label above), it won't compile:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[circle, draw] (c1) [label=left: text] {};
    \node[block, draw, right = of c1] (e1) [label=right: $1*1=1$] {};  
    \draw[->] (c1) -- (e1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Any thoughts on how I can make it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the math expression into `{}` to solve your problem

**Explanation**

As [@Zarko explained in his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414527/how-to-add-a-math-expression-in-the-label-outside-of-a-node/414528?noredirect=1#comment1035515_414528) the problem is not the math expression as such, but the `=` sign, as this will cause `tikz` to wrongly parse your options. With the additional layer of `{}` around the expression, the `=` will be hidden from tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \node[circle, draw] (c1) [label=left: text] {};
    \node[draw, right = of c1] (e1) [label=right: {$1*1=1$}] {};  
    \draw[->] (c1) -- (e1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

Comment: cause of problem is not math as such but sign `=` in expression.  to see this, try `label=right: $1*1{=}1$` (it also works). however, this writing destroy spacing around `=`. conclusion: your solution is better :-)

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for the explanation! May I add it to the answer?

Comment: of course, if you estimate that is helpful to op :-). the similar situation is for example with math expresion $\mathbf{x}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ where commas also cause error. if you will add to your answer, i will delete my coments

Comment: @Zarko Thanks - but please do not delete your comment, I am linking to it :)